# How to create a profile registration form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am trying to create a custom registration form, but I don't really know how to do it since I am trying to connect the default django registration with a new model.

here is what it looks like, it might be wrong but I am thinking to something like this.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)
```

**views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')

        context = {'profil':Profile.objects.all()}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email'}

    def save(self, commit=True):

        my_user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        my_user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        new_profile = Profile(user=my_user, name="John", description="a person")

        if commit:
            new_profile.save()

        return new_profile
```

**register.py**

```
<form action="/user/register/" method="post" id="register" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  {{ form.username.errors }}
  {{ form.username.label_tag }}
  {{ form.username }}
</div>
[... other fiels ...]
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

I'm trying to connect the model with the form, so when someone register and when I type his name in the template like this : `{{user.name}}` It should be "John".

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also in order to get the name in the template you have to access it like `{{ user.profile.name }}` since name is saved in the Profile Model

**But** if you want to create a form for your Profile model you can do it like this

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Profile
         fields = ("name", "description")
```

Also if you plan to use both the UserCreationForm and the ProfileForm both in the same HTML Form you should add a **prefix** to them to know which data belongs to which form, look how to do it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

**Edit**

```
def register_user(request):
    #...
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, prefix="user")
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, prefix="profile")
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm(prefix="user")
        profile_form = ProfileForm(prefix="profile")
    context = {
        "user_form": user_form,
        "profile_form": profile_form
    }
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Then in the template

```
<form action="/user/register/" method="post" id="register" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ user_form }}
    {{ profile_form }}
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
```

Comment: I want the last solution you proposed but how can I register an user that can authenticate, (fields = username, email, password1, password2, name, description)

Comment: Nailed it! I just pulled together a user form and profile form into the same registration process with this. Effortless. Thanks.