# Django User inheritance

Tags: django, database, authentication, django-models

I am building a food ordering website with Django. I want my users to register an account on my site, and they should sign in to actually order. I want to use the `User` class built in with Django, but that doesn't include necessary fields like address, confirmation ID, and phone number. If I build a custom `User` model, that doesn't have many good helper functions which I can use like `auth.authenticate`. I searched this topic, and I found that I could use `AbstractUser`. But when I inherited my `CustomUser` class from `AbstractUser`, some strange things began to happen. After some more research, I found out that changing the `User` model after applying my built-in migrations give some errors as there are some relationships or something.

I deleted my database and created a new one. Now, I am extending my `CustomUser` class from the built-in `User` class. This works fine, only you can't do `auth.authenticate` checking with the, confirmation ID for instance. Also, it seems to create two models every time I create a new `CustomUser`, the other on in the Users under the auth tab.

Can you tell me any good way to connect the `User` model with a few more fields after applying the built-in migrations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only want to add extra information and not change the default User behaviour, it is better to use the User Profile pattern instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model You can then include the profile fields in the user registration form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671318/how-to-create-a-profile-registration-form-in-django

Comment: @Selcuk, thanks! The `OneToOneField` is very helpful. If you could put it up as an answer, I would be glad to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend from `AbstractUser` and not `User` class ( behaviour you are experiencing is Multi-table inheritance (as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)))

Whole process of substituting default user model is well [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: I know, but like I said, I extended from `AbstractUser` and some problems came, for which the Django docs said that changing the user fields after applying the built-in migrations would cause some problems. Thanks for the multi-table inheritance bit though! :)

Comment: some problems are anticipated in this case, which is also documented
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project. In your last attempt you extended wrong class which is what I pointed on as incorrect, rest of process is normal, not sure what exactly are you asking then

Comment: I just saw your comment. Thanks, the docs link was helpful. Unfortunately, the project is done. I hope it'll be useful in another one. Note: Please tag me when you comment (@safwan)